# Split string in ksh

Tags: linux, string, shell, split, ksh

I got a string as follow :

```
foo=0j0h0min0s
```

What would be the best way to convert it in seconds without using date ?

I tried something like this that sounded pretty nice but no luck :

```
#> IFS=: read -r j h min s <<<"$foo"
#> time_s=$((((j * 24 + h) * 60 + min) * 60 + s))
ksh: syntax error: `<' unexpected
```

Any idea is welcome, I just can't use `date -d` to make conversion as it is not present on the system I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<<"$foo"` is mainly a bash-ism. It is supported in some/newer ksh. (google 'ksh here string' ).

Your read is trying to split at `:`, wich is not present in your input

If you first get rid of characters, you can split at blank (as ususal)
and changing the here-string to a here-doc

```
#!/bin/ksh

foo=1j2h3min4s
read -r j h min s << END
"${foo//[a-z]/ }"
END
# or echo "${foo//[a-z]/ }" | read -r j h min s
time_s=$((((j * 24 + h) * 60 + min) * 60 + s))
echo ">$foo< = >${foo//[a-z]/ }< = $j|$h|$min|$s => >$time_s<"

>1j2h3min4s< = >1 2 3   4 < = "1|2|3|4 " => >93784<

# or using array, easy to assign, more typing where used
typeset -a t=( ${foo//[a-z]/ } )
time_s=$(( (( t[0] * 24 + t[1]) * 60 + t[2]) * 60 + t[3] ))
echo ">$foo< = >${foo//[a-z]/ }< = ${t[0]}|${t[1]}|${t[2]}|${t[3]} => >$time_s<"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this code to work, it tells me `read: bad substitution` and `((j * 24 + h) * 60 + min) * 60 + s: bad number`

Comment: What ksh version you are using? Works for me with ksh `(AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`. In a bash I have at hand, I see additional qoutes if I add `echo "time_s=\$(((($j * 24 + $h) * 60 + $min) * 60 + $s))"`.  Without the quotes `"` within the here-doc it works.